# Show $R(mK_2,mK_2)=3m-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I have been asked to show (a homework problem) that the Ramsey number $R(mK_2,mK_2)=3m-1$. $mK_2$ is the graph of $m$ pairwise disjoint copies of $K_2$.

I know $K_2$ is just two vertices with one edge between them. My plan is:

First: Show that there cannot be $m$ different copies of $K_2$ in the complete graph $K_{3m-2}$. This means that there can never be $m$ copies of either colour which means that $R(mK_2,mK_2)>3m-2$.

Second: Show that there are always more than $4m$ edges which means that if we colour these edges with two colours in any way there will at least be $2m$ edges of one of the colours (according to pigeonhole principle).

Is this the correct idea? I do not know how to do the first step but the second should be something like
$$
|E(K_{3m-1})|=\frac{(3m-1)(3m-2)}{2m}=\frac{9m^2-9m+2}{2}=\frac{9m(m-1)+2}{4m}=\frac{9}{4}(m-1)+\frac{1}{2m}
$$
and since $\frac{9}{4}(m-1)>2$ for $m>2$ there will always be more than two groups of $2m$ edges.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

you've good ideas, but you are not exactly on the right track no. First a correction :  the complete graph on $n$ vertices, has $\binom{n}{2}$ edges, so about $n^2$ edges, much more than in your calculation :

$$\vert E(K_{3m-1})\vert = \frac{(3m-1)(3m-2)}{2}\neq \frac{(3m-1)(3m-2)}{2m}$$

Then as you said the first step is showing that $R(mK_2,mK_2) > 3m−2$. However this does not mean that there can **never** be $m$ different copies of $K_2$ in the complete graph $K_{3m−2}$. It means that there exists (at least) **one** red/blue edge-colouring of $K_{3m−2}$ such that there is no monochromatic $mK_2$. So you "only" have to exhibit such a colouring.

Then, showing that $R(mK_2,mK_2) \geq 3m−2$ : Again it does not mean that if we colour with two colours in any way there will at least be 2m edges of one of the colours. You need your coloured edges to form $mK_2$ which is a **disjoint** union of $m$ edges.

You should look into perfect / maximal matching in complete graphs.

Comment: When saying disjoint unions of $m$ edges, does this mean that we cannot use one vertex for different edges? For example if the edge incident to vertex $v_1$ and $v_2$ is coloured red, and edge incident to vertex $v_1$ and $v_3$ is red as well, then the edges $v_1 v_2$ and $v_1 v_3$ do not make a disjoint union of $2$ edges because they both use $v_1$.  Is that correct?

Comment: To show that $3m-2$ is not enough I take a graph $K_{3m-2}$ and colour all edges from $m-1$ nodes with red, and the rest of the edges blue. This way we can not have more than $m-1$ disjoint red edges. All blue edges and their vertices makes up $K_{2m-1}$ (since $3m-2-(m-1)=2m-1$), and here we cannot order the vertices in $m$ pairs in any way since $\frac{2m-1}{m}=2-\frac{m}{2}<2$ which means that there are fewer than $m$ blue $K_2$'s which means that there are not $mK_2$ in red nor in blue. Is that a correct reasoning?

Comment: I cannot really find a way to show the second step where I need to show that $R(mK_2,mK_2)\leq 3m-1$. You mentioned perfect matchings and in $K_{3m-1}$ I can see how a perfect matching where all edges are of the same colour would prove that $R(mK_2,mK_2)\leq 3m-1$ but I do not know how I could prove that. This idea would not work when $3m-1$ is odd either (at least not without modifications) so I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To show $R(mK_2,mK_2)>3m-2$, construct a graph $G$ with $3m-2$ vertices such that neither $G$ nor $\bar{G}$ contains a matching of size $m$. We can construct such a $G$ making $m-1$ independent vertices adjacent to every vertex of $K_{2m-1}$.

Showing $R(mK_2,mK_2) \leq 3m-1$ should be harder. I asked it here: [Show that $R(mK_2,mK_2)=3m-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603759/show-that-rmk-2-mk-2-3m-1)